# Does the latest version of OpenMDAO have a GUI for working with projects like earlier versions, such as 0.13 did?

Tags: openmdao

There are examples on youtube.com, for example, of a GUI for OpenMDAO in earlier versions. But I can't find any documentation or examples of a GUI for working with the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist in the latest versions 1.x.x.  There is an N^2 diagram available to help visualize things, but no GUI like the original. See the [docs](http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/usr-guide/tutorials/visualizing-model-connections.html) on how to use the N2 viewer

Comment: Well, that is the way it appears to me as well. But I was hoping that I was missing something.